# Download and replace file in directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying download a file from an URL, but the problem is when ever I open the downloaded file it opens the last file which I downloaded before! I mean if I download `image1.png` and open it , then try to download and replace `image2.png`,when I am going to open the last downloaded file, the file still `image1.png` !

Here is my code :

```
- (void)downloadDataFromMac {

    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:nil];

    NSString *replace = [absulutePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [absulutePath length])];
    pathWithData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.36:8888/?req=getimg&key=%@",replace];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:pathWithData];


    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSProgress  *progress;
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {


        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask]objectAtIndex:0];
        return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];


    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);

        //Hide HUD

            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

            self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:filePath];

            [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];

            [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];

        }];


    [downloadTask resume];

}
```

any help ?,thanks.

Comment: how can u replace file image1.png with image2.png ? It will always create a new path in document directory

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Saving images
-(BOOL) saveImage:(UIImage *) image filePath:(NSString *) filePath
{
    // Creating path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *fileFullPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath];
    // Saving image.
    BOOL success =  [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:fileFullPath atomically:YES];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(LogPropertyError, @"Couldn't save image to disk %@",fileFullPath);
    }
    return success;
}
```

Comment: Files are not just  images they are pdf and everything , but i'll try

Comment: writeToFile is a class method for NSData